# installing emacs and mercurial on suse

Tags: suse, zypper

I've some experience on Debian based distribution. There I've never had difficulties to install software like emacs and mercurial which I believe are quite standard packages in Linux OSes. Now I have a new laptop with Suse Enterprise. It seems that neither emacs nor mercurial are found in the list of installable packages...

I believe that I have to add some repository to zipper... So this is my actual list of repositories:

```
> zypper repos
# | Alias                                             | Nome                                              | abilitato | Attualizza
--+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------
1 | HP-SBSO-Emergency-Channel                         | HP-SBSO-Emergency-Channel                         | Sì        | Sì        
2 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Desktop-11-SP1 11.1.1-1.133 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Desktop-11-SP1 11.1.1-1.133 | Sì        | Sì        
3 | hd-889c0513                                       | SuSE-Linux-Updates                                | Sì        | Sì        
4 | hd-aeb4361a                                       | SuSE-Linux-Maintenance-Updates                    | Sì        | Sì
```

I found many repository lists but don't understand how to add any of them (a HREF to a .repo seems needed). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, don't have Enterprise, but openSuse12.3, xfce, which feels great, much faster than at earlier times. Quit nice with Emacs and DVC's. BTW Enterprise should have some kind of professional support(?)

Comment: I think the problem is that I skipped the registration pass during first boot (because internet was not available) and now I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

On SLE11, emacs is in the SLE11-SP1-Updates repository

```
Repository: SLES11-SP1-Updates
Name: emacs
Version: 22.3-4.36.1
Arch: x86_64
Hersteller: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
Support Level: Level 3
Installiert: Nein
Status: nicht installiert
Installierte Größe: 48,9 MiB
Zusammenfassung: GNU Emacs Base Package
Beschreibung: 
Basic package for the GNU Emacs editor. Requires emacs-x11 or
emacs-nox.
```

And mercurial is in the SDK repository:

```
Repository: SLE11-SDK-SP1-Pool
Name: mercurial
Version: 1.0.2-27.32
Arch: x86_64
Hersteller: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
Support Level: Unbekannt
Installiert: Nein
Status: nicht installiert
Installierte Größe: 2,8 MiB
Zusammenfassung: Scalable Distributed SCM
Beschreibung: 
Mercurial is a fast, lightweight source control management system
designed for efficient handling of very large distributed projects.
```

Get the SDK dvd from suse.com (login required)

You add repositories either via "zypper ar" or via yast.
You can only get update repositories if you have a valid subscription with SUSE.